# Minimum cost within limited time for a timetable?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have a timetable like this:

```
+-----------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+----+
| transport | trainnumber | departcity | arrivecity | departtime | arrivetime | price | id |
+-----------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+----+
| Q         | Q00         | BJ         | TJ         | 13:00:00   | 15:00:00   |    10 |  1 |
| Q         | Q01         | BJ         | TJ         | 18:00:00   | 20:00:00   |    10 |  2 |
| Q         | Q02         | TJ         | BJ         | 16:00:00   | 18:00:00   |    10 |  3 |
| Q         | Q03         | TJ         | BJ         | 21:00:00   | 23:00:00   |    10 |  4 |
| Q         | Q04         | HA         | DL         | 06:00:00   | 11:00:00   |    50 |  5 |
| Q         | Q05         | HA         | DL         | 14:00:00   | 19:00:00   |    50 |  6 |
| Q         | Q06         | HA         | DL         | 18:00:00   | 23:00:00   |    50 |  7 |
| Q         | Q07         | DL         | HA         | 07:00:00   | 12:00:00   |    50 |  8 |
| Q         | Q08         | DL         | HA         | 15:00:00   | 20:00:00   |    50 |  9 |    
| ...       | ...         | ...        | ...        | ...        | ...        |   ... | ...|
+-----------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+----+
```

In this table, there 13 cities and 116 routes altogether and the smallest unit of time is half an hour.
There are difference transports, which doesn't matter. As you can see, there can be multiple edges with same departcity and arrivecity but difference time and difference price. The time is constant everyday.

Now, here arises a problem.

A user wonder how he can travel from city A to city B (**A and B may be one city**), with passing zero or some cities C, D...(whether they should be in order depends on whether the user wants it to be, that is, there are two problems), **within X hours and also least costs** under above conditions.

Before this problem, I have solved another simpler problem.

A user wonder how he can travel from city A to city B (**A and B may be one city**), with passing zero or some cities C, D...(whether they should be in order depends), **with least costs** under above conditions.

Here is how I solve it (just take not in order as an example):

1. Sort the must-pass cities:C1, C2, C3...Cn. Let C0 = A, C(n+1) = B, minCost.cost = INFINITE;
2. i = 0, j = 1, W = {};
3. Find a least cost way S from Ci to Cj using Dijkstra Algorithm with price as the weight of edges. W=W∪S;
4. i = i + 1, j = j + 1;
5. If j <= n + 1, goto 3;
6. if W.cost < minCost.cost, minCost = W;
7. If next permutation for C1...Cn exists, rearrange list C1...Cn in order of the next permutation for C1...Cn and goto 2;
8. Return minCost;

However, I cannot come up with a efficient solution to the first problem, Please help me, thanks.

I'll be appreciated if anyone can solve another problem:

A user wonder how he can travel from city A to city B (**A and B may be one city**), with passing zero or some cities C, D...(whether they should be in order depends), **within least time** under above conditions.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a big problem, so I will just sketch a solution.

First, remodel your graph as follows. Instead of each vertex representing a city, let a vertex represent a tuple of `(city, time)`. This is feasible as there are only 13 cities and only `(time_limit - current_time) * 2` possible time slots as the smallest unit of time is half an hour. Now connect vertices according to the given timetable with prices as their weights as before. Don't forget that the user can stay at any city for any amount of time for free. All nodes with city `A` are start nodes, all nodes with city `B` are target nodes. Take the minimum value of all `(B, time)` vertices to get the solution with least cost. If there are multiple, take the one with the smallest time.

Now on towards forcing the user to pass through certain cities in order. If there are `n` cities to pass through (plus start and target city), you need `n+2` copies of the same graph which act as different levels. The level represents how many cities of your list you have already passed. So you start in level 0 on vertex `A`. Once you get to `C1` in level 0 you move to the vertex `C1` in level 1 of the graph (connect the vertices by 0-weight edges). This means that when you are in level k, you have already passed cities `C1` to `Ck` and you can get to the next level only by going through `C(k+1)`. The vertices of city `B` in the last level are your target nodes.

Note: I said copies of the same graph, but that is not exactly true. You can't allow the user to reach `C(k+2), ..., B` in level `k`, that would violate the required order.

To enforce passing cities in any order, a different scheme of connecting the levels (and modifying them during runtime) is required. I'll leave this to you.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not quite following you. Could you please post a more detailed descritption?